# JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-2012

Can someone help with this error in my code. I get this error when i start the website in Internet Explorer:

> JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

This is the code please help me what i need to change in the java script?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    div.world_map_container #transparent_map {
        border: medium none;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        z-index: 30;
    }

    ul li {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        z-index: 20;
    }


    #home_resen {
        background: url("Sliki/resen.gif") no-repeat;
        height: auto;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    #home_skopje {
        background: url("Sliki/skopje.gif") no-repeat;
        height: auto;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    #home_kocani {
        background: url("Sliki/kocani.gif") no-repeat;
        height: auto;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="world_map_container">
        <img src="Sliki/map.jpg" usemap="#the_world_map" id="transparent_map" />
        <map name="the_world_map" id="the_world_map">
            &nbsp;<area shape="poly" coords="167,335,168,321,166,318,161,313,156,308,148,308,146,304,143,302,137,301,136,293,133,283,130,277,127,273,127,270,129,266,133,261,133,253,132,248,128,242,124,240,121,240,118,243,114,248,108,254,100,258,94,261,92,261,91,268,87,274,83,279,81,281,81,286,81,291,81,295,75,298,69,304,67,308,66,316,69,318,79,319,86,319,88,321,91,324,94,326,100,325,102,322,103,317,100,315,95,314,88,312,85,308,87,303,90,300,94,297,98,294,104,293,109,293,113,295,119,303,124,311,127,318,130,327,131,335,132,338,135,336,140,332,144,331,148,331,151,333,155,336,162,336,167,335" href="Default2.aspx" id="area_resen" alt="Resen" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="171,45,167,47,161,47,162,50,167,50,167,53,164,55,157,64,161,68,169,88,172,89,175,102,175,105,179,105,180,109,187,116,187,118,202,121,202,124,212,124,216,121,216,116,245,116,253,113,255,110,254,104,253,103,259,103,265,104,269,105,272,103,272,95,274,90,277,87,282,86,285,84,287,78,288,76,280,75,274,74,270,72,265,67,263,63,257,63,254,60,251,57,250,56,247,57,241,56,237,55,234,52,229,49,227,44,227,38,231,35,233,33,231,31,226,29,225,28,225,21,220,20,216,22,213,24,212,26,210,28,207,28,205,26,202,26,200,28,199,31,196,33,192,39,188,43,189,45,189,47,185,50,179,52,175,52,172,50,171,47,171,45" href="Default2.aspx" id="area_skopje" alt="Skopje" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="397,47,388,47,383,56,384,61,384,66,382,70,379,71,375,71,375,76,373,82,372,88,372,94,377,96,389,109,408,109,409,98,405,92,409,89,406,80,412,80,421,77,424,74,423,68,429,66,425,63,415,53,398,53,397,47" href="Default2.aspx" id="area_kocani" alt="Kocani" />
        </map>
        <ul>
            <li id="resen"><a href="#">resen</a></li>
            <li id="skopje"><a href="#">skopje</a></li>
            <li id="kocani"><a href="#">kocani</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.world_map_container area').each(function () {
            // Assigning an action to the mouseover event
            $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
                var country_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', 'home_');
                $('#' + country_id).css('display', 'block');
            });

            // Assigning an action to the mouseout event
            $(this).mouseout(function (e) {
                var country_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', 'home_');
                $('#' + country_id).css('display', 'none');
            });

        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have not included `jquery` in your file.

Something like this:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Or if you have it already in your source files, include it from there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `jQuery` in order to use `jQuery`, see [how to use jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you reference jquery with a script tag

Answer (score 0):

I have this error in IE 11 because I link to my Custom `JQuery`file before linking to `Jquery` library.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to try this. Your internet explorer settings might not be allowing you to download the jquery files.

1. Click Internet Options.
2. Switch to tab Security, and then click Custom level...
3. Scroll down in the list of settings until you see the section
   Downloads.
4. Set all download options in this section to Enabled.
5. Click OK to save the settings.