# JavaScript error: "JavaScript runtime error: 'do_foo' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using some JavaScript in my ASP.Net page like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate_everything()
    {
        do_foo();
    }
</script>
```

where `MyScript.js` exists in the same directory as the `Default.aspx`, and contains this (only):-

```
function do_foo()
{
    var fred = 2;
    return fred;
}
```

When I attempt to run this (using Internet Explorer) it produces the error:-

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'do_foo' is undefined
```

The real code (with actual useful work) handled in the same way was working fine yesterday, and fine earlier this morning. I modified it and this error started appearing; I reverted the changes and the error still appears. Before, using Chrome, the real version worked. Now, nothing happens (I assume the reason is the same).

I appreciate this question is a hardy perennial. My problem differs from those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946547/javascript-runtime-error-is-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396807/javascript-runtime-error-fidocallback-is-undefined) in that I'm not using JScript, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100136/page-throws-javascript-runtime-error-function-name-is-undefined-ie10-only) in that I'm not adding the script from the code-behind.

I have used this approach in several other applications and the error does not occur there. Is that path going to pick up the file from the `Default.aspx` directory? Is there anything I need (in `web.config` or anywhere else) that I am lacking?

**Edit** on inspecting the page source (Chrome) the JavaScript in the `.aspx` file is listed as expected. The included file is shown thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyScript.js"></script>
```

but no script is shown (ought there to be?)

Comment: Is MyScript.js definitely being loaded by the browser? If so, is it the right version? (You may need to do a cache refresh)

Comment: Open Developer Tools in Chrome, and see if reports an error when trying to load `MyScript.js`. Go to the Sources tab and see if `MyScript.js` is listed.

Comment: @Barmar, I did as you suggested; the results are in the edit.

Comment: If it's not showing the script, it got an error while trying to load it. Go to the Network tab and then reload the page.

Comment: Is that the correct path?  could it be `src="/MyScript.js"`?  If you browse `http://localhost/MyScript.js` is it served?

Comment: If the script has been correctly loaded, you see the script in the tree panel under `sources` tab of your Chrome inspector or 'Network' tab of your Firefox inspector.

Comment: The script won't be shown on the page, just the reference to it. Have a look in the Sources tab to see if `MyScript.js` is listed there, and have a look in the Network tab to see if there was an error loading it when the page loaded.

Comment: @DavinTryon, that appears to be the problem. Sorry to have troubled you chaps. But now I wonder why it worked for so long, and why it works in other applications.

Comment: `src="MyScript.js"` will work for the *relative* path. Did you recently change the base path?  Or are you browsing at something like: `http://localhost/path/`.  In that case, the relative `src` will look for the file at `http://localhost/path/MyScript.js`

Comment: @DavinTryon, I am activating the application from Visual Studio. Sorry, I should have mentioned this.